# M1 Macで、x64 のコンテナは動作しますか？

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

現在、開発用Macの購入を検討中です。
開発のなかで、Docker Desktopを利用して複数のx64コンテナをローカルで動作させる必要があります。
このときkubernetesも利用します。

コストパフォーマンスを考えてM1アーキテクチャのMacにしようかと思っています。
ただ、x86 や arm64 が動くという記事はありましたが、x64 に言及した記事がありません。

x64 のコンテナは Rosetta2 などを使えば M1 Mac でも動作するでしょうか？

Comment: Rosetta 2 は system-emulationには対応しない予定のようです。[Docker Desktop for Apple silicon](https://matsuand.github.io/docs.docker.jp.onthefly/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/)によると, Docker自体のシステム要件として(いまはまだ) Rosetta 2が必要とのこと。Intel ベースのコンテナーを動かす際の system-emulationには [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/)が使用される模様。注目すべきはそちらかも

Answer (score 1):

2021 年春現在における個人的な回答としては、「おおよそ動くと思いますが、社内開発用に展開するのであればとりあえず 1 台買って技術検証してからの方が良いと思います」が穏当でしょう。

Rosetta 2 は当然 x86_64 に対応しており、[Docker Desktop for Apple silicon](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/) も 2021/04/15 リリースの 3.3.1 にて正式に対応が発表されています。ただしエミュレーションさせながらの実行は稀にクラッシュする可能性はある、との注釈付きではあります。

徐々に対応が進んでいっていることと思いますが、アプリケーションによってはエミュレーション実行が上手くいかないものもまだ残っている可能性があります。またエミュレーション以外の部分で詰まる可能性もあります。つまりユースケースに依存するので、とりあえず 1 台導入してみて検証するのが早い……と個人的には考えています。一応 Kubernetes については現状 github.com/docker/for-mac にある open issue が[ゼロ件になっている](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20kubernetes%20label%3Aarea%2Fm1)のですが、Kubernetes に載せるアプリケーションの都合もあるはずです。